# Python 3: Each row just adds on from the past row. How can I just make it so that each line is new numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

```
import random

number_of_balls = int(input("Enter number of balls: "))
number_of_slots = int(input("Enter number of slots: "))
path = list ()
slots = list (range(0, number_of_slots))
direction = ["L", "R"]
i=0



def BallPath ():
    balls = 0
    while balls < number_of_balls:
        balls += 1
        order_of_path = random.randint(0, (len(direction) -1))
        path.append(direction[order_of_path])

    for x in path:
        print (x, end=' ')
    print("\n")

for i in range(0, number_of_slots):
    BallPath()
```

This is my code

And the output looks like:

```
Enter number of balls: 2
Enter number of slots: 2
L L 

L L L R
```

It's suppose to do two random numbers in two rows but after the first line it adds on from the past line. How can I fix that?

Comment: Move `path = list()` into the `BallPath` function. Why did you put in the global scope anyway?

Comment: Thank you! I am new to programming in python. Now that I look at it I can see why putting path = list() in the global scope is a problem.